# X11 window doesn't take up whole screen in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, display, osx-yosemite, x11-forwarding

I'm running a remote piece of software on my macbook via ssh (Lumerical FDTD Solutions). When I open this software GUI, it opens an X11 window.

I'm having issues resizing my X11 window. The top of the window seems to be constrained by an invisible barrier; I cannot drag the window upwards from a certain point (about 30% from the top of the screen). This means that my X11 application can only take up about 2/3 of the screen.

I didn't have this problem before upgrading to Yosemite (I was using Mavericks before).

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem but on a very different Mac using very different X applications.  Mine is a Mac Pro from 2011, running four monitors on two ATI Radeon HF 5770 video cards.  Every X program that I tried had the same problem as you describe.

I did the upgrade to Yosemite on my MacBook, but the version of X was earlier (2.7.5 instead of 2.7.7).  So I took the X11 on my Mac Pro down to 2.7.5 and then it worked on three out of four of my monitors (2.7.7 gave the problem on all four).

I ultimately erased the file `~/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist` to reset the preferences, and this seems to have solved the problem entirely.  I have not yet tried this out with the newest version of X11.

Comment: I guess the multi monitor setup is the problem - at least at my 13" MBP. But only, when an X11 is used the first time. What I did is quitting X11, unplugging my external screen, deleting the file ~/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist, starting an X11 app. Now it can use the whole screen. Reconnecting my external screen did not screw it up again.

Comment: Same issue here with 2.7.7 and having an external monitor connected.  Had to use @Grmpfhmbl technique of closing X11, disconnecting the external monitor, removing `~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist` and starting X11.  Reconnecting the external screen did not screw it up.